# Create mysql query for BC date and AD date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to fetch date between BC to AD dates. In my database BC date(like -000002-04-01) and AD(like 0004-04-01). i want to fetch with MySQL query dates between BC to AD date. I write MySQL that

```
SELECT * FROM `hg_timelines` WHERE start_date BETWEEN '-000002-01-01' AND '0005-01-01'
```

but i'm also got results as start_date like -000020-04-01,-000347-01-01,-001200-01-01,-001987-03-02,-002017-01-02,-120000-03-01 and so on...

In fact i changed MySQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM `hg_timelines` WHERE start_date >='-000002-01-01' start_date <='0005-01-01'
```

but i got same results.

can some one help me what is right MySQL query that i'll get exact results for searching functionality?

Comment: Get used to read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). "The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'." With that, check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/best-way-to-handle-dates-prior-to-1000-a-d-in-mysql) answer if can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but I stumbled on this because I was working on a similar project. Technically, AD starts as soon as BC is over. BC is from approximately 4004 BC to 0. AD goes from the end of BC to whenever God decides to end time. No one knows. AD stands for "Anno Domini" in latin ("The Year of our Lord" in English) as opposed to the commonly decoded error "After Death". Of course BC stands for Before Christ. Now in the astronomy world there is a debate based on the actual berth of Jesus. Some say 2 BC and some say 4 BC based on the also debated death of King Herod.  All that being said we can get to the MySQL. If you want a date that happened during the 33 year life of Jesus you can do something like this:

SELECT *
FROM `hg_timelines`
WHERE (start_date BETWEEN '-000002-01-01' AND '000031-04-01')

or

SELECT *
FROM `hg_timelines`
WHERE (start_date BETWEEN '-000004-01-01' AND '000029-04-01')